# Why doesn't Evolution use the login keychain?

Tags: 12.04, evolution, seahorse, keychain

I use evolution as an email client but it's annoying in that it doesn't use the 'login' keychain. Every time I log in there's a pop asking for the password to keychian 'Default' which is the one Evolution creates.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `seahorse`, right click on the "login" keyring in the list, and choose "Set as default" in the menu.